# WebSolr Heroku, default installation breaking the server start

Tags: heroku, websolr

I'm trying to install WebSolr on Heroku. I chose the 20$/month package.
I followed the instructions on the addon page:

I added the following to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'sunspot_rails', '~> 1.3.0'
```

In heroku config, I also have a proper URL:

```
WEBSOLR_URL:          http://index.websolr.com/solr/xxxyyyzzz
```

When starting the server, I get the same error both locally and in the heroku logs:

```
/Users/patricegagnon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb:297:in `join': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
from /Users/patricegagnon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb:297:in `user_configuration'
from /Users/patricegagnon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb:281:in `user_configuration_from_key'
from /Users/patricegagnon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb:256:in `disabled?'
from /Users/patricegagnon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails.rb:30:in `build_session'
from /Users/patricegagnon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sunspot_rails-1.3.3/lib/sunspot/rails/init.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/patricegagnon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /Users/patricegagnon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
```

...

The server refuses to start, I can no longer have access to any of my controllers. I have not done anything else thus far. Anyone know why this generic Solr integration break my server startup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Sunspot 1.3 because you're also running Rails 2.x, you need to run `script/generate sunspot`.  If you're using Rails 3 or 4, you should update to a newer Sunspot.  Latest at the time of this comment is 2.1.